# Error while waiting for device: The emulator process for AVD .... was killed

Tags: android, android-studio, android-emulator, android-virtual-device

I am a freshman for the development of the Andriod, I suffered from a odd question when I runned the app ,just as the follow picture.

[image]

I also google it, but I have not finded a useful answer, who can tell me what I can do ~~~~(>_<)~~~~
thanks

Comment: Can anyone help with this situation? me too facing the same problem.

Comment: I'm an old man with years of development behind me in all sorts of languages and IDEs, and here I am with the same "Error while waiting for device: The emulator process for AVD Android_Accelerated_Nougat was killed"

Comment: Not enough space in the disk may also cause this issue. Try to free up some space and try restart the AVD again

Answer (score 4):

I found this:

just go to this directory:

```
cd $ANDROID_HOME/Sdk/emulator/lib64/libstdc++
```

and rename: `libstdc++.so.6` to `libstdc++.so.6.bak`

`$ANDROID_HOME` is your android SDK directory

source: https://forum.manjaro.org/t/android-studio-installation-guide/12630

Comment: Linux: mv libstdc++.so.6 libstdc++.so.6.bak

Comment: did not work on macOS. I can't find this directory nor can I find the files in the package contents of Android Studio. Nor does this command work