# Android killing AVD emulator

Tags: android-emulator, android-virtual-device

I am getting : `Error while waiting for device: The emulator process for AVD Nexus_S_API_23_Marshmallow was killed.` in the 4:run log. It's all the data Android Studio gives me.

I tried the answers from [this question to no avail.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39000249/error-while-waiting-for-device-the-emulator-process-for-avd-was-killed)

I've tried [turning the graphics into software. That didn't work.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43893913/why-is-the-android-emulator-starting-but-then-dying-immediately)

I am at my wits end trying to debug this error.

BTW since I am a beginner coder I don't know what data i should provide in this answer so if you need more information just tell me what .

Comment: Same here. Try to run or debug and it doesn't work and I get this message.

Comment: Tried again and it worked. Android Studio really is a complete piece of rubbish.

Comment: @RichardBarraclough id have to agree.